# Multiple File upload on customizable product not working in magento 2.4

Tags: magento2

[If I add only one file option then it is working fine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lasj.png)

[If I add two option then it is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqTlP.png)

Comment: Can you be more specific, add more detail on what you want to do and describe precisely what is going wrong ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
please check this link : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/336074/multiple-file-upload-on-customizable-product-not-working-in-magento-2-4

I want to add to cart with multiple images.
If I add only one option for file upload then it is working fine. but I add multiple file upload option then it is not working.